# My `TextChangedEvent` fires on `FormLoad` event and gives an error. Input string not in correct format

Tags: c#, textchanged

Here is my `TextChanged` event.

```
private void Price_Discount_MarginBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToDecimal(profit_MarginTextBox.Text) > 0)
    {
        Company_List_PriceTextBox.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(list_PriceTextBox.Text) - (Convert.ToDecimal(list_PriceTextBox.Text) * (Convert.ToDecimal(discountTextBox.Text) / 100))) / Convert.ToDecimal(profit_MarginTextBox.Text)).ToString();
    }
    else
        Company_List_PriceTextBox.Text = list_PriceTextBox.Text;
}
```

The various text boxes are set with a string value of 0.00 unless populated with the data from the bound `Data Table`.  The `textChanged` event is on three different `textbox`.

Comment: You are making this too complicated. The "string is not in the correct format" error (a FormatException, actually) is caused by one of the Convert.ToDecimal calls. Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on those lines, and look at the values you're trying to convert.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between `error` and `error type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is add check a data is valid string or not . if text is null it won't consider null = 0 .

Try this

```
decimal demo;
if(decimal.TryParse(profit_MarginTextBox.Text,out demo)){
if (Convert.ToDecimal(profit_MarginTextBox.Text) > 0)
    {
        Company_List_PriceTextBox.Text = ((Convert.ToDecimal(list_PriceTextBox.Text) - (Convert.ToDecimal(list_PriceTextBox.Text) * (Convert.ToDecimal(discountTextBox.Text) / 100))) / Convert.ToDecimal(profit_MarginTextBox.Text)).ToString();
    }
    else
        Company_List_PriceTextBox.Text = list_PriceTextBox.Text;
}
```

From your request

```
Would you be able to tell me how to put Line 5 on multiple lines for easier reading?
```

Try this

```
decimal margin = Convert.ToDecimal(profit_MarginTextBox.Text);
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(list_PriceTextBox.Text);
decimal discount = Convert.ToDecimal(discountTextBox.Text);
decimal total = 0;
if (margin > 0)
   total = (price - (price*(discount/100)))/margin;
else
   total = price;
Company_List_PriceTextBox.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: TryParse has fixed the problem. Thanks.  Would you be able to tell me how to put `Line 5` on multiple lines for easier reading?

Comment: Yes, I had that.  I just thought there might be way similar to when you use the `@` in a `SQL` statement.